# AWS Cloud9 couldn't connect to SSH server ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

Getting this error. While connecting Cloud9 with SSH
**AWS Cloud9 couldn't connect to SSH server ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx**

I checked Security group is ok. 
check IAM Rule is ok.

I followed every step of this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZdvbGArONk&t=351s

but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you check selinux and iptables rules?

Comment: DId you ever find out what your error was

Comment: Check the region that your workspace is saved under. I'm having trouble connecting to Europe-1 instances from the AWS Cloud9 console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Umar some additional things you can take a look at:

I would say check your instance is actually the ubuntu instance otherwise the user would be ec2-user@xx.xx.xxx.xx.

Then I would check the public ssh key step is correct:

- The public key is the right key for your private key
- When you are sshing you are using the -i option to specify the location of that private key i.e. ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx -i
  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- Then check the ssh agent ssh-add -l and make sure the private key is loaded into the agent.